# show that function $f:\mathbb{R \to\mathbb{R}}$ defined by $f(x)=|x|^{p}$ for $p\geq1$ is a convex function.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, convex-analysis

show that function $f:\mathbb{R \to\mathbb{R}}$ defined by $f(x)=|x|^{p}$ for $p\geq1$ is a convex function.

hint is given that use slope criterion .but how to apply slope criterion here .

please help

Comment: You can also derive and check how the derivative behaves. What do all derivatives of convex functions have in common?

Comment: can you use higher derivatives?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner function  is not differentable at $x=0$. so how can we apply derivative criterrion here?

Comment: $f$ is differentiable for $p>1$. For $p=1$ the claim is just the triangle inequality.

Comment: for p > 1 it is Minkowski's inequality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: I suggest you to prove the simple following assertion

If $f: R \to I $ is convex and  $g: I \to R $ nondecreasing and convex then
 $gof: R \to R $ is convex .

Just apply definition.